# window.onfocus to reload page results in unending loop only in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, onfocus

I'm trying to reload a webpage using `window.onfocus`

```
window.onfocus = function(){ window.location.reload(); }
```

It works fine in Safari and Chrome, but causes an unending loop of page reloading in IE.

Is there another way to achieve this that will force a reload for `window.onfocus` but will not force a reload for `window.onload`?

(I'm trying to force a page reload in order to update a status message after a user submits a form on a different tab and then returns to the tab with the status message.)

Comment: seems like a bad solution. Use postMessage

Comment: I don't think postMessage will work. The status message is part of a web page and is based upon a database query checking for the form submission... all of which is generated by a WordPress plugin. I need to find a way to reload the page .onfocus but not .onload... or I may have to just abandon having the page content be updated after coming back to that browser tab.

Comment: why? If the page is done, it sends a post message to the other page to update.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the use of postMessage then (the one example I looked at appeared to use postMessage to trigger a popup, so I made the bad assumption that it was about popup type messages)... are you saying I can use postMessage to tell the other page to reload?

Comment: That is what I am hinting at.

Comment: Okay... I'll need to do some more reading then!

Comment: In doing my search about the use of postMessage, I stumbled across what appears to be a simpler solution... curious if there are downsides to this: if I add window.opener.location.reload() to a file triggered by the form submission, the originating tab is reloaded.